# How to do efficient bulk insert on child table together with a single insert on parent table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say that I have these two table:

```
create table parent (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique
);

create table child (
  id serial primary key,
  name text not null unique,
  parent_id integer not null references parent(id)
);
```

As you can see, the `child` table has references to `parent` table.

What I want to do is bulk insertion on `child` table together with
inserting single value on `parent` table in a single query if possible.
So, I have to insert a value to `parent` table first with `with clause`,
and then grab the returning `id` and insert it to `child` table.

For, example I want to insert these values:

- parent1
- child1
- child2
- child3
- child4

And this is my query to do this insertion:

```
with x(id) as (
  -- insert parent's name first
  insert into parent (name)
  select 'parent1'
  where not exists (
    select * from parent where name = 'parent1'
  )
  -- get the parent_id
  returning id
), y(parent_id) as (
  -- ensure that parent_id has a value even if the insertion
  -- above is not inserting anything.
  select x.id as parent_id from x
  union
  select parent.id as parent_id from parent where name = 'parent1'
)
-- bulk insert to child table
insert into child (parent_id, name) values
((select parent_id from y limit 1), 'child1'),
((select parent_id from y limit 1), 'child2'),
((select parent_id from y limit 1), 'child3'),
((select parent_id from y limit 1), 'child4');
```

This query works as expected. But, i doubt about it's efficiency. Because,
in real usage, I will insert around 300 values on child table.

So, can anyone show a more efficient query than this one?

Comment: If `parent.name` is unique why isn't it the primary key?

Comment: Actually, my tables have more columns than that. And my table using integer id as primary key. Is using `parent.name` as primary will help in this case?

Comment: `insert into child (parent_id, name) select parent_id, n from (select parent_id from y limit 1) as p cross join (values ('child1'),('child2'),('child3'),('child4')) as c(n);` - shorter a bit.